# ¿Qué cantidad de números hay entre un rango de a y b? (ciclo while)

Tags: ciclos, while, pseint

No sé cómo realizar este ejercicio con el ciclo `while`, lo he hecho con el ciclo `for` pero con el ciclo `while` no encuentro la manera. Los pseudocodigos (hechos en *PseInt*), serían de la siguiente manera ():

Algoritmo xy

```
c<-0
Escribir "Ingrese el  valor inicial"
leer x
Escribir "Ingrese el valor final"
leer n
Para i<-x Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
escribir"i= " i
c<-c+1
Fin Para
Escribir "La cantidad de valores separados desde " x " a " n " es : " c
FinAlgoritmo
```

El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente:

- Dado dos valores enteros `x`, e `y`, ambos **mayores que cero**, contar la cantidad de números que hay dentro de ese rango de valores determinados por x, e `y`.

Ejemplo: `X es 5  -  Y es 10`.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado, así llamas la atención de más personas y evitas que cierren tu pregunta :D

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tiene que hacer repetir el ciclo mientras x sea menor a n (el valor de i es el valor de x que ingresa el usuario). Segundo, incrementar el valor de x para permitir la salida del bucle) y también el valor de i.

```
Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir c, i, x, n Como Enteros;
    c<-0;
    Escribir "Ingrese el  valor inicial";
    Leer x;
    Escribir "Ingrese el valor final";
    Leer n;
    i<-x;
    Mientras x < n Hacer
        Escribir "i= ", i;
        c<-c+1;
        i<-i+1;
        x<-x+1;
    FinMientras
    Escribir "La cantidad de valores separados desde ", x, " a ", n ," es : ", c;
FinProceso
```

Answer (score -1):

Te adjunto un código en C que podría ayudarte.

```
main(){

int i,x,y,total=0;

printf("\nIngresa el valor inicial: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
printf("Ingresa el valor final: ");
scanf("%d", &y);

i=x;
while(i<=y){

    total++;
    i++;
}

printf("\nEl total de numeros es: %d ", total);

}
```

Comment: Gracias si me ayudó